# SequelizeEagerLoadingError 'Model 1' is not assoicated to 'Model 2'

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am using **sequelize version:5.21.2**, and has the following error: 'Tweet is not associated to User!'

```
Error: { SequelizeEagerLoadingError: Tweet is not associated to User!
    at Function._getIncludedAssociation (D:\References\Youtube\Sequelize\sequelize-1-hour\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:715:13)
    at Function._validateIncludedElement (D:\References\Youtube\Sequelize\sequelize-1-hour\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:619:53)
    at options.include.options.include.map.include (D:\References\Youtube\Sequelize\sequelize-1-hour\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:516:37)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

I have two models

**Tweet.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

//sequelize comes from global.sequelize in connection.js
const Tweet = sequelize.define('Tweet', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
    allowNull: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  userId: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
  content: Sequelize.STRING(300)
});

Tweet.associate = function(models) {
  Tweet.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
};

module.exports = Tweet;
```

and **User.Js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

//sequelize comes from global.sequelize in connection.js
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
    primaryKey: true
  },
  username: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(35),
  },
  passwd: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(20),
    allowNull: false
  }
});

User.associate = function(models) {
  User.hasMany(models.Tweet);
};


module.exports = User;
```

and the code which throws error is

```
  const users = await User.findAll({
    where: { id: '1' },
    include: [Tweet]
  }).catch(errHandler);
```

I don't know how to include Tweets when a user is fetched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined functions, inside your models, that create your associations. However, you never call these functions. After instanciating your `Sequelize` object and initializing your models, you should run the following code to have your associations created:

```js
for(let modelName in sequelize.models) {
  sequelize.models[modelName].associate(sequelize.models);
}
```

See:

- [Sequelize models member](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-member-models)
- [Iterating through objects in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/for...in)